# Setting up Axiom3D (or finding a 2d C# openGL engine)

Tags: c#, .net, 2d

I have a computer that won't let me enable direct3d acceleration (i've tried almost everything).

So I need a 2d engine in c# that supports openGL.

I found Axiom3D, but I can't run the samples and I can't build the project, and it's driving me crazy. When I try to run the samples, it just blits open the command prompt and closes right away.

Comment: Why don't you try setting a breakpoint and stepping through to find where it dies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a computer that won't enable 3d acceleration via Direct3D there's a good chance that it won't support OpenGL either - or at best only support it in software rendering mode.

If the Axiom3D samples open a a command prompt and then fail closing the window try opening a command prompt first, then running the sample from that:

```
cd C:\axiom3d\samples <-- or where ever it's actually installed
sample1.exe <-- or what ever it's actually called
```

This should show you the output and leave the window open, giving you the opportunity to read it. You could also redirect the output to a log file for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might try OpenTK.  It's a lightweight wrapper around OpenGL for .NET.  As far as C API wrappers go, it's a pleasure to use in .NET.

I share your frustration with Axiom3D.  It seems great, but getting the thing running is a helluva lot of effort.  Also there seem to be three different branches to choose from, just to add to the confusion.